# SSIS splitting columns on commas within strings

Tags: csv, ssis

This seems to be non-standard behavior, so I'm a bit confused.  I have a CSV file I'm trying to load into a table with SSIS.  A few of the fields are strings and have commas within the double quotes.  The Flat File Connection I'm using is splitting these strings into multiple columns, which I don't want it to do.  For example:

```
"Name", "Location"
"John Doe", "New York, NY"
```

The above is being parsed as 2 header columns and 3 data columns.  How can I stop it from splitting within the strings, and only splitting the elements?

Comment: In your flat file connection manager, what have you specified for the `Text Qualifier`?

Comment: Doh!  I knew it'd be something simple - I hadn't specified anything.  Putting the " in there fixed it.